# Importing a coloured .otf

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea

I'm working on a project that requires the use of a custom coloured .otf font, where every letter has a unique colour. I've tried double clicking to install it and simply using font-family, adding it to my IntelliJ project and linking it with @font-face but it doesn't seem to work. The letters are black no matter what I do.

Is there a proper way of doing this, or a workaround?

Comment: Font files contain essentially colorless definitions. Unless you use custom `SVG` files with painstaking custom styling to mimic letterforms, you won't be able to use a "custom-colored font, where every letter has a unique color" in a browser. Any text rendered will always use a single color unless otherwise styled via CSS; in other words, each letter will inherit the color per cascade (which by default is black).

Comment: Support for [Opentype SVG COLRv0+1](https://css-tricks.com/colrv1-and-css-font-palette-web-typography/) istill quite spotty. Firefox and Chrome have solid support safari recently removed support (9.2023). Desktop Application? AFAIK some Adobe apps. There is not much you can do.

Comment: Only some fonts such as Noto Color Emoji are supported. As the IDEA uses theme features(users can switch dark or light themes), all chars' colors will be changed to follow the theme colors.